# (Java 8) java.util.function.Supplier

Tags: java, java-8, supplier

In the following code, I tried to call the info method taking a Supplier. (The info method is overloaded: one is taking a String and the other is taking a Supplier.) The compiler complains that "The method info(String) is not applicable for the argument `Supplier<Double>`". My expectation is to call the info method taking a Supplier by sending a Supplier object. Can I get some help to understand this error?

```
Supplier<Double> randomSupplier = new Supplier<Double>()
{   public Double get()
    {   return Math.random(); }    
};

logger.info(randomSupplier); <----
```

Comment: Seems `info` requires `Supplier<String>`. Please post more information

Comment: What is the type of `logger`?  Is this a standard logging package that we can look at to find the overloads of `info` or is it something homegrown?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: Sun: Thanks. I missed that thinking it is taking Supplier<T>, not Supplier<String>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your `logger` is a `java.util.logging.Logger` . . .

According to [the Javadoc for `Logger.info`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#info-java.util.function.Supplier-), it expects a `Supplier<String>`, and you're giving it a `Supplier<Double>`.

To fix this, you need to give it a `Supplier<String>`. You can write one either like this:

```
final Supplier<String> randomSupplier =
    new Supplier<String>() {
        public String get() {
            return Double.toString(Math.random());
        }
    };
```

or like this:

```
final Supplier<String> randomSupplier =
    () -> Double.toString(Math.random());
```

You can even write:

```
logger.info(() -> Double.toString(Math.random()));
```

and Java will magically infer that your lambda is meant to be a `Supplier<String>` (because the other overload of `info` doesn't take a functional interface type).

Comment: This is the answer.   I thought it is taking Supplier<T>, not Supplier<String>

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way getting `Supplier` in java 8 way and logging by converting `Supplier` to `String`

```
Supplier<Double> randomSupplier = () -> Math.random();
info(randomSupplier);

  private void info(Supplier<Double> randomSupplier) {
    System.out.println(randomSupplier.get());
 }
```

Comment: I know that if I pass a String, it compiles. What I wanted to do is to call one of the overloaded info taking a Supplier object (This method is defined in the Logger class.) by passing a Supplier object. I am passing an instance of an anonymous object implementing the Supplier interface.

Comment: Thank you, @Steve for clarification; I tried this for the problem above: private void info(Supplier<Double> randomSupplier) {
    System.out.println(randomSupplier.get());
  }